# get option name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a select tag in HTML form

I wanna get option name (attribute) when select on change

What can I do?

i very search in google but i not found

HTML form write with Django

my code:

```
<form action="{% url 'busi:add_business' %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %} {{business_form.as_p}}
     <select name="" id="provinses">
     </select>
     <button type="submit">افزودن</button>
</form>

var provinces = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "آذربایجان شرقی",
        "slug": "آذربایجان-شرقی"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "آذربایجان غربی",
        "slug": "آذربایجان-غربی"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "اردبیل",
        "slug": "اردبیل"
    },
    
]

for (var i = 0; i < provinces.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("option");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(provinces[i].name);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    node.setAttribute("name", provinces[i].id)
    document.getElementById("provinses").appendChild(node);
}


const selectElement = document.querySelector('#provinses');
selectElement.addEventListener('change', optionName)

function optionName(e) {
    var name = this.name;
    console.log(name)
}
```

Comment: you know how to set attribute `name`. so basically the same you can do just with get attribute name. You can find it in google how to do it. Other thing is to bind select onchange event

Comment: [option elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element) don't have names. They have `value`s. The name belongs to the `select` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can get it by accessing select's `value`.

```js
var provinces = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "آذربایجان شرقی",
        "slug": "آذربایجان-شرقی"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "آذربایجان غربی",
        "slug": "آذربایجان-غربی"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "اردبیل",
        "slug": "اردبیل"
    },
    
]

for (var i = 0; i < provinces.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("option");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(provinces[i].name);
    node.setAttribute("name", provinces[i].id)
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("provinses").appendChild(node);
}


const selectElement = document.querySelector('#provinses');
selectElement.addEventListener('change', optionName)

function optionName(e) {
    var opts = this.options;
    console.log('Selected id', opts[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name'));
    console.log('Selected value', this.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="provinses"></select>
```

Comment: No, that gives the text content of the element (since there are no `value` attributes). The question is asking for the `name` attribute.

Comment: @Quentin since they're identical in this context I don't see any difference.

Comment: Now see, my bad. OP wanted to get number, I get the value.